# Validation inactive user Django

Tags: django, django-users, django-login

I looking for a resolving of my issue.
I have custom User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In my app I have e-mail-confirmation. When I create user I hit the "is_active=False". When user activate account then flag "is_active=True". Everything works good.
But when INactive user tries to log in I wanna get message from Django in Login form.
Django has it(source code):

```
def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
            )
```

But doesn't work for me.
Update: When inactive user tried to log in I get same message as user with incorrect username or password.
I tried to override AuthenticationForm:

```
User = get_user_model()
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:                # tried with Meta and without
        model = User
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError('There was a problem with your login.')
```

View:

```
class CustomLoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginView):
    form_class = CustomAuthenticationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    success_message = "You was logged in successfully"
```

url:

```
path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Update, templates base and login:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {% block mystyle %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cabinet' %}">Cabinet</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">LogOut</a>
            {% else%}
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">SignUp</a>
            <a class="nav-link text-right" href="{% url 'login' %}">LogIn</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-success">{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="row justify-content-center p-4">Log In</h1>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <div class="container p-2">
                <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot your password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="container p-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean saying "doesn't work"? No error is shown on form? Does your template render form errors?

Comment: I did not get error if user is in_active, but, for example,I get error message if login or password is invalid. Both errors are in same form validation in Django: (error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    })

Comment: Update: When inactive user tried to log in I get same message as user with incorrect username or password.

Comment: @koko Yes the inactive users object will never reach the Form as the Authentication Backend is already preventing that. You can check the code of `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`

Comment: @koko Also it's good that the error doesn't show in the form, else people might be able to find out if some username is used and is inactive, The best thing would be just to add a message / text somewhere in the page (by default) that if they can't sign in to confirm that they have activated their account.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, thanks for your answers. I understood it from point of security. I resolved it just override ModelBackend. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Charnel thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood it from point of security. I resolved it just override ModelBackend

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend  
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
UserModel = get_user_model()
class CustomModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):   # here (remove 'and self.user_can_authenticate(user):')
                return user
```

Settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.backends.CustomModelBackend',
]
```